# TemplateNotfound error while converting notebook into pdf

Tags: jupyter, nbconvert

I have a .ipynb file in my virtual environment. I have following packages installed ;

```
nbconvert 6.4.0
pandoc    2.17.0.1
texshop    4.62
```

Inside my virtual environment I run this command;

```
 jupyter nbconvert --to pdf transit_time_notebook.ipynb
```

But it is failing with this error message;

```
File "/Users/jsingh/.local/share/virtualenvs/operational_quality-CNT8izRC/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jinja2/loaders.py", line 566, in load
raise TemplateNotFound(name)
```

`jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: index.tex.j2`

Can I please get some help to how to fix this issue?I feel I have all required libraries needed for nbconvert to work.
Help is appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

From what I'm reading in nbconvert documentation, it seems that the command you need is `jupyter nbconvert transit_time_notebook.ipynb --to pdf transit_time_notebook.pdf`.

https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html